# Gradle + Dropwizard + Shadow -> Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, gradle, dropwizard, microservices

I'm trying to create a simple microservice using Dropwizard and Gradle as a build system. 
No database, only REST endpoint to expose.

So I have a controller:

```
@Path("/domainurl/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class SimpleController {

    @GET
    public Example resourceExample() {
        return new Example("something");
    }
}
```

My application main class:

```
public class Application extends Application<MyConfiguration> {

    @Override
    public void run(MyConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
        final SimpleCOntroller controller = new SimpleController();
        environment.jersey().register(controller);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Application().run(args);
    }
}
```

Example is a simple value object with one string property, MyConfiguration is an empty class at this moment.

And build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:1.2.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

mainClassName = "com.example.Application"

//
dependencies
//

run {
    args 'server', './src/config/microservice.yml'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.1'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': mainClassName
    }
}
```

But after build, when I type:

```
java -jar MyApp.jar
```

I'm still getting:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.Application
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `com.github.johnrengelman.shadow` plugin is used you need to execute `shadowJar` task and run artifact created under `<project_root>/build/libs` with name `<name>-all.jar`.

BTW: I know that you provided only parts of the code but I found some errors here (e.g. `SimpleCOntroller` and `SimpleController`). [Here](https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/getting-started.html) a great tutorial on getting started with dropwizard can be found.

Comment: I changed real names during writing the question, this is why there could be a spelling.

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet for a shadowJar task in my case? I'm completely new to gradle, since I've been using maven all the time.

Comment: This task is already provided with this plugin: `com.github.johnrengelman.shadow`. Run `gradle tasks` and verify if it's present in the output. Then run it.

Comment: I'm glad that You've worked it out. Gradle is a very powerful build system, however might be difficult for beginners.

Comment: @Opal what happens if you still get that Error? Can you maybe help me in my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36291195/gradle-application-plugin-ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same error. Just be attentive you're adding "server your-file-name.yml" to the program arguments but not VM options ;-)

Comment: Doh! Thank you for saving me from myself.