# Java 9 gives "Main Class not found" ob Ubuntu, but file works on Windows and Mac // how to find main Class in OpenJDK

Tags: ubuntu, java

So I have a jar file that works perfectly fine on Windows and Mac, but not on Ubuntu (the only place where Openjdk is installed)
This question hints at OpenJDK being the problem: [Java Application main class not found on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36291195/java-application-main-class-not-found-on-ubuntu)
So: how do I show OpenJDK the correct Main Class? (Its Client.class in /chat in the jar file) I know it has something to do with the MetaINF File, but I cant guess the correct input there.
This is what's currently in the MANIFEST.MF file:

> Manifest-Version: 1.0
>
> Main-Class: Chat.Client

I cant find anything anywhere on the topic, but I also cant install the proprietary java on the Ubuntu PC, as its the one where the jar HAS to run and the one where I m not admin at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer but an easy workaround for people with the same Problem: Install (installing is optional, you can use it directly after the download) the proprietary JDK from Oracle, and if you dont have admin privileges (I dont): you dont need them, simply download the Java JDK from oracle and start the .Jar with /pathtothedownloadedJDK/bin/java instead of "java" and then the usual -jar yourJarFile.jar

Tl:Dr: Get the JDK from Oracle, you dont need sudo to use it.

Answer (score 0):

> Its Client.class in /chat in the jar file

Then `Main-Class: Chat.Client` is incorrect, it should be `Main-Class: chat.Client` (lower case `chat`).

So probably not an OpenJDK issue, just the fact that some file systems are case-insensitive and others are case-sensitive. You're almost certainly using a case-insensitive one on Windows. I guess you must be on Mac as well, though I find that surprising. You probably aren't on Ubuntu.

Comment: *(Couldn't decide whether this was a pure typo/non-repro "not useful to others in the future" question. I don't think so, the fact that case can matter in some environments and not others is significant and could well be useful to others in teh future.)*

Comment: @Hobbamok: There's no reason to be rude, particularly to someone who was kind enough to spend some of their time to try to help you. By "You probably aren't on Ubuntu" I meant "you probably aren't [using a case-insensitive file system] on Ubuntu." (Quite a normal construction in English to contrast sentences like that.) Did you try specifying the correct class name? `chat.Client`, not `Chat.Client`?